# if not any(map) does not work

Tags: iterator, anaconda, python-3.5, any

I am seeing unexpected behaviour from `if not any()` under Anaconda 3.5.2:

```
    matches = map(get_valid_matches, self._patterns)

    if not any(matches):
        return False

    print(any(matches))
    print(list(matches))
```

Console output:

```
    False
    []
```

I'm scratching my head as to what is going on here. How is it reaching the `print` statements?

Comment: The first `any` consumed the iterator.

Comment: Ah, so a solution is `matches = list(map(get_valid_matches, self._patterns))`. Thanks. I just upgraded from Python 2.7, so this is new behaviour for me.